# Python Selenium: Find object attributes using xpath

Tags: python, xpath, selenium

I am new to xpath, trying to get value of the "value" using xpath:

```
<input type="submit" value="  Search  " class="long searchButton" style="width:190px !important;">
```

while it is easy to find element by `"type="submit"` like:

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@type='submit']")
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to get the values I need, as:

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@type='submit']/@value")
```

somewhat expectedly gives an error:

```
expression "//*[@type=\'submit\']/@value" is: [object Attr]. It should be an element
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

EDIT:
The xpath is correct, but it "returns" an obj attribute and as it is not an element, it is not allowed. I can't find a method like get_attr_by_xpath(), or anything similar.

Comment: perhaps this is a silly suggestion but does using raw strings fix: `r"//*[@type='submit']/@value"` ?

Comment: have you tried something like `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Search')]").click()`

Comment: When I tried your xpath with lxml it worked fine. I tried `lxml.html.fromstring(s).xpath("//*[@type='submit']/@value")` and the o/p is `['  Search  ']`

Comment: @ hayde -- raw string doesnt't fix it.

Comment: @ RanRag -- yes, xpath seems to be correct, the problem seems to be with "find_elemnts", as object attribute is not an element. However there doesn't seem to be a method like get_attr_by_xpath or anything similar for browser object.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I finally used `get_attribute("value")` as:

```
for i in browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@type='submit']"):
    print i.get_attribute("value")
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be like this

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@type='submit']/@value").text
```

**Update:**

With the function used by you, we can only extract the element not its attribute. To get its attribute, the expression should be something like this

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@type='submit']").get_attribute("value")
```

Ref: 
http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.find_elements_by_tag_name

Comment: @ Kaipa -- your update is also the closest thing i found. However. There shoul be 'find_element' not elements or a for loop if using elements.

Comment: @Jayy: yeah, It worked ! you're right.  find_elements_by_xpath() function just tries to get an **element**, not an **attribute**. So, I got an errror when I want It returns an attribute. I just put get_attribute() following, then done. Thks !