# python clicking a button on a webpage

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I currently have a script that logs me into a website and I want to have it click a button on the website if it is currently not clicked. Here is the info for the button:

When the button is already active:

```
<p class="toast_btn">
    <a class="button grey toast track-click active" data-user-avatar="https://dwebsite.net/picture.jpg" data-checkin-id="123456789" data-href=":feed/toast" data-track="activity_feed" href="#">
```

When the button is not active:

```
<p class="toast_btn">
    <a class="button grey toast track-click" data-user-avatar="https://dwebsite.net/picture.jpg" data-checkin-id="123456789" data-href=":feed/toast" data-track="activity_feed" href="#">
```

I am only looking to click it when `class="button grey toast track-click"`

What is the best way to do this? I currently use urllib2 and mechanize to login and check a few forms currently. Thanks!

Comment: You'll want something like BeautifulSoup for working within the HTML: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 24):

When I compare the two tags I see that the difference is for the **class** tag.
So if you can read it then you're done

You can do it with Selenium if you like

Step 1: find the XPath
 - Get the XPath of the button: for that right open the page in Chrome click on it and select Inspect element
 - It will open the html file and right click on the highlighted line and select copy Xpath
 - Copy the XPath in NotePad

Now that you have the XPath you can select the button via a Python script and query the attributes

Here is a prototype

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.youradress.org")#put here the adress of your page
elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@type='submit']")#put here the content you have put in Notepad, ie the XPath
button = driver.find_element_by_id('buttonID') //Or find button by ID.
print(elem.get_attribute("class"))
driver.close()
```

Hope that helps, if you have question please let me know

I used these links for documentation

[Python Selenium: Find object attributes using xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579061/python-selenium-find-object-attributes-using-xpath)

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: I tried using selenium but because it is a page I am logged into, it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: what do you observe? you can log using selenium also. did you try?

Comment: I am using `toast_link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Toast')` but I need to cursor through them now. Can I put a for loop in similar to `for find_element_by_link_text('Toast') in driver:`?

Comment: what does the Xpath give you? not finding it?