# How to automate the "next" or "previous" button clicking on webpage after end of video?

Tags: python, html, selenium, automation

I want to automate the clicking of the "next" or "previous" button on this website. http://www.toonova.com/cartoon.

The "next" and "previous" buttons however are not labeled this way on any of the links. Instead the buttons titles are the cartoon name and episode number. the increasing episode number means "next" and decreasing numbers mean "previous episode". Example here: http://www.toonova.com/denver-the-last-dinosaur-episode-5

**My question is how could I mimicking this solution([python clicking a button on a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869225/python-clicking-a-button-on-a-webpage)) using selenium or something similar allow the application to wait till the video is done playing and then to go on to the next episode?**

The main objective if it helps, is to allow the user to pick a cartoon series and let them either pick 'UP' or 'DOWN' from any point in the series to have the series go up in episodes or down in episodes.

hope the question makes sense.

thank you in advance.

Comment: for next button you can  use capth : '//*[@id="elinks"]/a[2]' and for previous button '//*[@id="elinks"]/a[1]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the "locating the links problem", you can locate the "previous" and "next" links this way:

```
previous, next = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#elinks > a")
```

As far as waiting for the videos to finish - I'm not sure, these are flash player videos and not HTML5 videos which would be much easier to interact with.

Comment: according to the link below the user has provided a solution to flash players let me what you think!

http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/934/does-selenium-work-with-video

Answer (score 0):

**[pyautogui](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui)** module in Python can be used for simulating mouse movements and clicks. Here is an example to move to a set of coordinates (100,100) and click:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.moveTo(100, 100)
pyautogui.click()
```

It is surprisingly easy. You can read **[Automate the Boring Stuff with Python](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/)**.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the suggestion, I will definitely read what you linked.