# Python extracting element using bs4, very basic thing I think I don't understand

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I'm using Beautiful Soup to try to get an element off of a page using the tag and class. Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Send a GET request to the webpage
url = "https://www.hindawi.com/journals/am/2021/1623076/"
response = requests.get(url)

# Parse the HTML content of the webpage
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')


results = soup.find_all('span', class_ = 'simpleShowMore')
print(results)
```

which I pretty much took directly from their example. If you look at this website, there are values there and it's not being found by BS. The site looks like this:

[image: Trying to extract this string]

The output of this is:

[]

I'm sure I am doing something very simple wrong. I believe a lot of the examples I found are out of date. Please help?

Thanks

Comment: The `span` element doesn't use the mentioned CSS class. Try to find the `div` element(s) with the class first and then in the result the `span`(s) without the class.

Comment: As with many BeautifulSoup questions on StackOverflow, this page loads as some HTML with a lot of JavaScript, which won't get executed by `requests`. You'll need something like `selenium` to get the JavaScript executed, so that you can use BS4 on the resulting document. In this case, you can also consider just getting the JSON object from the loaded source, given that the data you are after is right there - you can save the effort of first rendering it out to HTML and then parsing the HTML back into data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you would like to obtain the address of all institutions.

If you analyze the source code of the website, you can see that the information is, contradictory to the other answers and comments, already loaded and will be displayed by a script afterwards. Since this is the case, you do not need to use Selenium or any other tool to perform the click to load the data.

Here is an example of how you can access the information:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json

# Send a GET request to the webpage
url = "https://www.hindawi.com/journals/am/2021/1623076/"
response = requests.get(url)

# Parse the HTML content of the webpage
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

# Extract text of the element containing the data that could get loaded
new_data = soup.find(attrs={'id': '__NEXT_DATA__'}).text

#
data = json.loads(new_data)

# Extract Data and transform it into an array
join_address_lines = lambda entry: ', '.join([line['addrLine1'] + ', ' + line['addrLine2'] + ', ' + line['addrLine3'] for line in entry['addrLines']])
address_lines_array = list(map(join_address_lines, data['props']['pageProps']['article']['affiliations']))

# Printing the results
print(address_lines_array)
# --> ['School of Architecture and Materials, Chongqing College of Electronic Engineering, Chongqing 401331', 'College of Geography and Tourism, Chongqing Normal University, Chongqing 401331']
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I have a lot to learn!

Answer (score 0):

With `soup.find_all('span', class_ = 'simpleShowMore')` you are trying to find all *span* tags that have a class of *simpleShowMore*. The span you've selected doesn't have such class - actually is classless.

You could try instead

```
results = soup.select('div.articleHeader__affiliations__affiliation span')
```

Answer (score -1):

Well... Yes, it's really simple. What you want to parse is dynamic content.
Check source before clicking `show more`. There would be no `span` here.

What you need to do is:

1. Select wanted `simpleShowMore` - be aware that there is more than one.
2. Click it.
3. Run parsing code

[There is another question how you can do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869225/python-clicking-a-button-on-a-webpage)