# Scraping from a website and output is truncated

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the authors from this URL: https://doi.org/10.1155/2021/2122095

And it is grabbing only 3 of the writers, with the fourth being truncated into an ellipse in the output.

Here is the code:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# URL
url = 'https://doi.org/10.1155/2021/2122095'

# Send a GET request to the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# Parse the HTML content
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

   
authors = soup.find("meta", {"name": "authors"})['content']
    

print(authors)
```

This is the output:

Datian Bi | Jingyuan Kong | ... | Junli Yang

Why why why? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the tag that you have used to find the authors. Please check the source code view-source:https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jhe/2021/2122095/. There is only one meta tag with the name 'authors' and it contains the string you are getting. That means that your program works correct.

```
<meta name="authors" content="Datian Bi | Jingyuan Kong | ... | Junli Yang">
```

I assume that you like to get all the authors. To do so you could use:

```
list(map(lambda x: x.getText(), soup.findAll("span", {"class": "articleHeader__authors_author"})))
# --> ['Datian Bi,1', 'Jingyuan Kong,1', 'Xue Zhang,1', 'and Junli Yang2']
```

or

```
list(map(lambda x: x['content'], soup.findAll("meta", {"name": "citation_author"})))
# --> ['Bi, Datian', 'Kong, Jingyuan', 'Zhang, Xue', 'Yang, Junli']
```

Comment: Just in adition - In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)

Comment: Wow, what sorcery is this? This is fantastic thank you. Can you maybe point me in the direction of learning how this works? I believe it could help me with another problem I posted here a few days ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78050876/python-extracting-element-using-bs4-very-basic-thing-i-think-i-dont-understand

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how you can get all 4 authors from the page:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://doi.org/10.1155/2021/2122095"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

authors = []
for a in soup.select(".articleHeader__authors_author"):
    if a.strong:
        authors.append(a.strong.text)
    else:
        authors.append(a.find_next(string=True))

print(*authors, sep="\n")
```

Prints:

```
Datian Bi
Jingyuan Kong
Xue Zhang
Junli Yang
```