# Retrieve src="http..." with selenium Xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath

First time here...

```
<img alt="blabla..." src="HTTP://www.blabla..jpg">"
```

My code:

```
listF = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[*]/div[*]/div[*]/div[*]/a/img")

for list in listF:
        print(list.text, '-yo')
        print(list.tag_name)
        print(list)

Returns:

' -yo'
'img'
'selenium.blabla(session = "xxx-xx...", element ="{b7a50cbe-76xx-x...}")>'
```

What I need is to retrieve

```
src="http://britcar.com/shopimages/products/thumbnails/A/AWR/AWR1374.jpg"
```

Is there any way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks really like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579061/python-selenium-find-object-attributes-using-xpath.

Comment: @alecxe +1 looks like a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

What you are printing is the WebElement object itself and what you require is an attribute of the WebElement object.

You should try this :

```
list.get_attribute("href")
```

considering the href attribute is in the image tag and not the anchor tag.
If the href is in the anchor () tag, you should change your xpath to :

```
/html/body/div[]/div[]/div[]/div[]/a
```

Comment: Hi there, tksIit Works with ("outerHtml")

Comment: Just saw your HTML code.

You can use 

    list.get_attribute("src")