# Finding XPath without using inspecting element?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am making an automation for download data from a weather institution.

The issue is that in my effort to make it more independent I am trying to make Selenium to Tab keys to a certain spot, so the Browser focus can "Walk" to the download button. When I call the click() function it doesn't do anything. So I tried to Extract the XPath with the function get_attribute("xpath") but it returns `None`. How I can extract the XPath?

I am going to paste the issue down here:

```
Bandera=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/input')

Bandera.click()

Bandera.click()

## So Here i just select and dis-select a checkbox just to be near the Download button.

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB * 1 )
actions.perform()

#Here i just tabed to the button

Accion=driver.switch_to.active_element

#Maybe, here is when i lost the focus of the button?

Descarga_Actual=Accion.get_attribute("xpath")
```

Thank you and sorry to borrow your time.

Comment: Did you see the answer?

Answer (score 0):

To make a click on hover I would use the following sequence:

```
your_dropdown_locator.click()
dropdown_option = driver.find_element_by_xpath("dropdown option locator")

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(dropdown_option)
actions.click().perform()
```

But, this is the approach that is usually used for **dropdowns**.
You use: `driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/input')` This is the main problem of your code.
If you pasted html code of this dropdown (or button you need to click), people would help you to find a better locator. XPath/CSS must be unique. In your case the locator is very bad.

Also, I see no sense making `Bandera.click()` two times.

In your case, as I understand, you just need to click the button. So the locator is your main problem.
You need to find the correct locator, to wait till the button is clickable and then to click it.

Another problem in what you are trying to do:

`get_attribute("xpath")` looks like incorrect expectation of how *get_attribute* function works. Check at least here what this function means [Python Selenium: Find object attributes using xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579061/python-selenium-find-object-attributes-using-xpath)